# c# saving multiple times within the range

Tags: c#

Hi I have a simple problem. I have to Register a book multiple times within a range. for example I have 3 books with a Title "C# Prog" It will automatic save 3 times and will auto increment the Book ID. Looks like this..

```
Book Title       Book ID
C# Prog            001
C# Prog            002
C# Prog            003
```

This is what I have tried.

```
SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection("Sample Con String");
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

 try
        {

            da.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Reg_Book VALUES (@Received_From, @Date_Reg, @Bin_Num, @Accession_Num, @Publication, @Author, @Title, @Copies, @Volume, @Remarks)", cs);
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("Received_From", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = comboBox3.Text;
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("Date_Reg", SqlDbType.Date).Value = dateTimePicker5.Value.ToShortDateString();
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("Bin_Num", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = textBox36.Text;
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("Accession_Num", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = textBox2.Text + "-" + textBox14.Text +"-"+ textBox15.Text +"-"+ textBox26.Text;
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("Publication", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = textBox37.Text;
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("Author", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = textBox47.Text;
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("Title", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = textBox48.Text;
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("Copies", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = textBox49.Text;
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("Volume", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = textBox50.Text;
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("Remarks", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = textBox51.Text;

            cs.Open();
            da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cs.Close();
            }




        catch (Exception a) 
        {
            MessageBox.Show(a.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing a loop.....or is there some other question?

Comment: Does the above code work for inserting a single row?  If so, just wrap it in a function and call it three times.

Comment: Can you clarify your question and your issue? You would just need a loop on how many books you want and increment that number each time.

Comment: Yes sir. How can I insert a loop if I will input a range of 1-3? sorry sir Im new in c#.

Comment: Can you explain why you need to store 3 times the same information?

Comment: To make it easy to store multiple books sir. for example the title of the book is "Prog c#" and it is 50 pcs.

Comment: and also to identify what book is missing or borrowed.